# django - Overwriting files with default_storage.save()

Tags: django

I'm using `django.core.files.storage.default_storage` function for saving files, but I don't see an option where I would specify that existing ones have to be overwritten. I'm looking for some simplest and cleanest solution, so do I have to write my own function for checking if file exists, and if it does to delete it before saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/overwrite.html).

It has an overwrite storage backend that does what you're looking for.  You just need to update your settings.py to use the OverwriteStorage class:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.overwrite.OverwriteStorage'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file and then save, look at this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

file = ContentFile("Some text", name="data.txt")
path = f"/path/to/{file.name}"

if default_storage.exists(path):
    default_storage.delete(path)
    
default_storage.save(path, file)
```